# Where are the gem files located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Where are the gem files located ?
I'm new to rails and trying o understand how the whole gem functionality works. 
My question is how can i follow a gem installation in order to confirm a gem is been installed ?
Where are the installed files located ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From within your rails app, you can list out all of the gems being used, their versions, and the local path:

```
bundle show --paths
```

There's no reason to modify any of these files though.  Configuration is typically done through an initializer in /app/initializers, but it depends on the gem being used.

If you need to modify something about the gem, you should fork it on Github and then reference the git location in your Gemfile until your pull request makes it back into the gem:

```
gem 'some_gem', '4.1.1',  git: 'https://github.com/some_github_repo/some_gem.git'
```